# Use absolute value of linker command file variable in 'C' code

Tags: c, embedded, linker

I have a linker command file that assigns the top address of the stack into a variable

```
_stack = . + 0x80000;
```

I want to use this address in a 'c' program - I want to copy the stack to another location and then update the stack pointer to point to the new location before doing a destructive memory test on the orginal bank of RAM.

I'm finding that if I do something like

```
extern u32 *_stack;  
myFunction(_stack);
```

Then the function seems to get passed the value stored at the stack location

```
lwz r3,0(r8)
```

Rather than the address of the stack itself.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
extern u32 _stack;
U32 * stackPtr;
stackPtr = &_stack;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the most natural [ie: correct] way to declare this is based on the notion of thinking of the stack as an array in memory with the stack pointer being a location within that array:

```
extern U32 _stack[];
U32 *stackPtr;
stackPtr = _stack;
```

Answer (score 0):

*myFunction(&_stack);* should pass myFunction the address of the variable * _stack*.
Else, it will pass the value contained in the variable *_stack*.